# Run a docker container from python

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to 'port' this (working) shell command:

```
IMAGE_NAME="myimage"
CONTAINER_NAME="myname"
docker run -d --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME tail -f /dev/null
```

to start a container from an image to python with:

```
import subprocess
IMAGE_NAME="myimage"
CONTAINER_NAME="myname"
subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'run',"-d","--name %s" % CONTAINER_NAME,"%s" % IMAGE_NAME])
```

but if fails with:

```
unknown flag: --name myname
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you `docker run --help`?

Comment: No, my problem is my lack of understanding of how to combine command line args/options in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everywhere that you put a space in the arguments should be a different element in the list. It thinks that `"--name myname"` is a single flag. Have you tried:

```
subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'run', '-d', '--name', CONTAINER_NAME, IMAGE_NAME])
```

Answer (score 5):

Docker has its python library exposing the Docker API so you can work with containers in a programmatic way, calling methods on them, etc.

https://github.com/docker/docker-py

If you want to stick to the subprocess way, you need to put each argument to a separate element in the list you pass to `check_output()`. Note that arguments are separated by a whitespace, regardless of whether one argument is a value to a switch, like in `--name name` - those are still two arguments. Of course, if arguments are grouped in quotes, e.g. `--name "a name"`, then the whole `a name` part would be a single element in the subprocess call.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of code bellow based on 
https://github.com/docker/docker-py library

```
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
container = client.containers.run('28_googleplay_root_x86_64:latest', name='your_name', detach=True, ports={'5556/tcp': 5556, '5555/tcp': 5555}, devices=['/dev/kvm'])
```

Container will be created and detached.
Library documentation can be find here https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html